# why forwarding of custom domain not work to g cloud compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

forwarding of custom domain not work to g cloud compute engine.as i can access my application with external IP address and port like http:x.x.x.x:8080/ but when i go to go-daddy for forward my domain to g cloud compute engine it doesn't show anything and not work, how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Get into google cloud DNS](http://console.cloud.google.com/networking/dns/zones)- its hanging off Networking on your [google dashboard console](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard)

Create a Zone for your domain which will supply you with a NS Type record with typical values like

```
ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-c4.googledomains.com.
```

Get into your godaddy and update your domain's NameServers with above values

Once you deploy and have a valid IP put it into a Type A record back on your google cloud DNS by clicking on ADD RECORD SET ... only value you change is the IPv4 Address field